# Why does offsetHeight vary in Firefox

Tags: javascript

The following code yields 15 for the offsetHeight in IE and Chrome, and in most installations of FireFox, but I've come across a few cases (3 computers, so far) where FF yields 14. I uninstalled and reinstalled FF and still got the same results.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="abc">ABC</span>

<script>
console.log(document.getElementById('abc').offsetHeight);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've compared the actual pixel height of the text, and it's the same between the browsers.  If I put a border around the text, it reveals that Chrome is leaving three pixels between the top of the text and the top border (and the same on the bottom), whereas FF leaves two pixels at the top and three at the bottom.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not totally sure on this one but i know browsers behave differently. I've seen people 'reset' tags at the beginning of CSS. `p{margin: 0; padding: 0;}' Then create your own classes for what you need to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a strict doctype, and do a css reset:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I still get a different value in Chrome and FF with that fix:  http://jsfiddle.net/mGfb4/14/

Comment: @BumbleB2na: your test returns 14 in IE and 15 in Chrome :( I've also tested a possible workaround from "[Vadikom](http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/)" But the same values are returned. I guess this makes these properties useless...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rendering in ["quirks mode"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Try adding a `doctype` at the very first line to trigger standards mode. This should even out a few quirks in rendering. Also consider [CSS resets](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) as well to normalize a few other browser quirks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
```

I also have to mention that [you don't need a DTD to trigger standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE). You only need the doctype declaration.

> The DOCTYPE is retained in HTML5 as a "mostly useless, but required" header only to trigger "standards mode" in common browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with inline elements such as `<span/>`.

If you add in this css, it will restrict the line-height of the #abc element and change its display type to inline-block so that it can still act like an inline element in some ways:

```
#abc {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

This is the best solution I can come up with and one that all browsers seem to all agree on. It is a known fact that [.offsetHeight and .offsetWidth are inconsistent cross browser](http://vadikom.com/dailies/offsetwidth-offsetheight-useless-in-ie9-firefox4/) however, I have only been able to isolate the issue to inline elements without diving in to W3C documentation or bug reports.